# Information for Statement of Earnings

Tags: canada

In Ontario, Canada, what information must be on a Statement of Earnings? I work as an independent contractor for a company, and thus receive money weekly as well as don't sell goods. I know that the CRA has a template somewhere on their website, but is it mandatory to follow it? I don't see the need to include cash sales, credit sales, sales returns, total sales etc. as I'm paid weekly.

What information is required on a Statement of Earnings in Ontario, Canada, and does it need to be the same as the CRA provided template?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the required information to for your tax records, and other record keeping requirements, any invoice format is accepted. The basic requirements are the contractor's name, the date and the amount.

If you are registered for GST/HST, there will be additional requirements based on the amount of the invoice. Here is a link to the details:
http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/bspsbch/itc-cti/nvc-eng.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give an answer of "go ask an accountant".  On the other hand an accountant answered.  So, I'll have to ask a question of my own here.